# What is the meaning of the variable before "=>" in a Scala Action definition?

Tags: scala, playframework

This is a basic controller action in play framework with scala.
Can you please explain what is the request variable. Is it the action parameter?

```
def echo = Action { request =>
          Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
        }
```

Comment: The title should give some clue what the question is about. For instance "what is the mening of the variable before "=>" in a scale Action definition?"

Comment: I don't know... Does [Scala anonymous function syntax and return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826610/scala-anonymous-function-syntax-and-return-type) cover it, or do you want to know anything more specific about Scala Play Requests what is not covered [by the api](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... let me add more information to it.

```
def echo = Action { request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
}
```

is actually,

```
def echo = Action({ request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
})
```

is actually,

```
def echo = Action.apply({ request =>
  Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
})
```

is actually,

```
def echo = Action.apply((request: Request) => {
  Ok.apply("Got request [" + request + "]")
})
```

And, if you are still finding it confusing... then you need to read basics of Scala.